# What does casting char array to long does?

Tags: c++, casting

The author of this code states that `(long)tab` returns address of the tab. Is it true? If yes, why is it so?

```
  char tab []= "PJC"    
  cout << " tab = " << tab << ", address: " << (long)tab << "\n" << endl;
```

Comment: If it's the address you're after, it should be cast to `void *`.

Comment: Author(not me) says(in the code) that `(long) tab` returns address. I do not get what is the even logical explanation what does `(long) tab` does.

Comment: I did read that, and I'm just saying I don't know why the author chose `long` over `void *`. `long` forces the memory address into an integral type, but `sizeof(long)` might not even be big enough to hold the value in some cases, though in practicality, that's probably never going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, its true. Raw arrays in C/C++ are considered so that their name is the pointer to the first element. So, you can write:

```
char tab[] = "PJC";
char c = *(tab + 1); // c ==  J
```

As pointer is no more than an integer value representing the address in memory, casting pointer to long will print you the address value.

You must be sure that integer would hold all values. Pointers always matches word size, so on 32-bit CPU a pointer is 4 byte, in 64-bit it is 8 byte and you'll need 64-bit integer not to have overflow - what exact type is it depends on the system (may be `long long`). You can use [intptr_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) (thanks @Avt) to store pointer values.

Comment: @Yoda Depends of architecture. On most 64-bit systems int is still 32 bits while pointers are 64 bits. If you want to use a type that is big enough for both an int and any pointer, use intptr_t or cast to `void*`

Comment: "As pointer is no more than an integer value representing the address in memory" - although this is true on common PCs, it is not true for the whole range of systems on which C++ can be used. The `void *` type exists to guarantee that an address can be held, so there is not really any reason to try and use `long` for the job.

Answer (score 1):

`Typecasting` a variable changes its interpretation, but the actual value remains the same. If you were to print the value with format specifier `%x` then you'll always get the same result, what typecast you use won't matter.

In this case, `tab` is a `char*`, which is nothing but an "address" of the location.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast to `void*` to get the address. Run following to check

```
char tab []= "PJC"    
cout << " tab = " << tab << ", address1: " << (void*)tab << ", address2: " << (long)tab << "\n" << endl;
```

But remember that result depends of architecture!

Comment: I only try to understand what `(long)tab` did in this code. I try to understand sb elses code.